# Prompt user for input then print smallest number

Tags: javascript, compare, prompt

Im trying to accept 2 inputs from a user then compare the 2 to find the smallest number.

Finally print to the console. I feel Im going in the wrong direction.

Any advice?

Below is my code

```
//prompt variable for user input
let num1 = prompt("Enter 1st number ", "i.e. 7 ");
let num2 = prompt("Enter 2nd number ", "i.e. 4 ");


// for loop returning lowest input

for (let i = 1; i < num1.length; i++){
    if (num1[i] <= num2){
        num2 = num1[i];   
    }
}

console.log(num2);
```

Comment: JavaScript has a built in `Math.min()` function. All you'd have to do is `console.log(Math.min(num1, num2));`  
  
EDIT: And yes, the approach here is wrong for several reasons:  
  
1. Start counting from 0;  
2. Your number input should be converted to a number and then used in a simple comparison;  
3. Looping through a string input number in this way would return incorrect answers. For example, 71 would be greater than 90 because 1 > 0, and that's where your loop starts and ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only 2 inputs and you're trying to console.log the smallest number then you can just use an if statement. No need to iterate through num1.

```
let num1 = 5;
let num2 = 10;

if(num1 > num2){
   console.log(num2);
}else if (num2 > num1){
   console.log(num1);
}else{
   console.log(num1 + ' and '+num2+' are equal');
}
```

Comment: if I needed to do this twice more, Can i simplify it with a loop?
Instead of writing out else if over and over for example

Comment: Yes, the best option would be to append all the user inputted numbers into one array and then iterate through the array to find the smallest number or you could simply use Math.min() function on the array to get smallest number.